# Boolean returns true every time I run my code

Tags: java

The code below should search through both arrays to find any similar numbers, and return `true` if one is found:

```
public class ArrayIntersect 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        main();

    }

    public static void main() 
    {
        boolean l = false;
        intersection(l);
        if(l = true)
        {
            System.out.println("There are matching variables in the arrays!");
        }
        else
        System.out.println("There are no matching variables.");

    }

    public static boolean intersection(boolean l) 
    {
        int[] one = new int[2];
        int[] two = new int[2];
        one[0] = 1;
        one[1] = 2;
        two[0] = 1;
        two[1] = 3;

        for(int i = 0; i < one.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < two.length; j++)
            {
                if(one[i] == two[j])
                {
                    l = true;
                    return l;
                }

            }
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < two.length; j++)
        {
            for( int i = 0; i < one.length; i++)
            {
                if(two[j] == one[i])
                {
                    l = true;
                    return l;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I apologize if the error is simple as I'm just starting on this website and learning Java! Also, any tips on making the program would be appreciated as well!

Comment: Guess what `if(l = true)` is doing...

Comment: `l = true` assigns `true` to `l`, `l == true` tests whether or not `l` is true.

Answer (score 4):

This

```
if(l = true)
```

is assignment. You wanted

```
if (l == true)
```

or just

```
if (l)
```

the side effect of the assignment is the value assigned. So `l = true` both assigns `true` to `l` and evaluates to `true` in the `if`.

Also, your code has a few other issues. The first you need to know is that Java is always pass by value. And you don't need to pass a `boolean` in. Finally, I think you really wanted

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean l = intersection(); // <-- can't modify caller's "reference"
    if (l) {
        System.out.println("There are matching variables in the arrays!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("There are no matching variables.");
    }
}
```

Then there's no need to iterate your two arrays a second time. And you might build them more simply like

```
public static boolean intersection() {
    int[] one = { 1, 2 };
    int[] two = { 1, 3 };

    for (int i = 0; i < one.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < two.length; j++) {
            if (one[i] == two[j]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to know if l is true you do:

```
if(l == true)
```

if you want to say the value of l is true, you do:

```
(l = true)
```

I modified your code to below:

```
public class ArrayIntersect {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    main();

}

public static void main()
{
    boolean intersect = intersection(); // intersect returns true/false
    if(intersect)
    {
        System.out.println("There are matching variables in the arrays!");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("There are no matching variables.");

}

public static boolean intersection()
{
    int[] one = new int[2];
    int[] two = new int[2];
    one[0] = 1;
    one[1] = 2;
    two[0] = 1;
    two[1] = 3;
    for(int i = 0; i < one.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < two.length; j++)
        {
            if(one[i] == two[j])
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < two.length; j++)
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < one.length; i++)
        {
            if(two[j] == one[i])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Please note that if you want to find out if 2 sets intersect, there are more efficient ways to do this. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Do not return inside for loop if you want to find out intersection of both for loop results. As in current case when array one and two are equal at 0 location you are out of the method . To resolve this Save the value in flag variable create a method and get the sum o/p